# softtabstop == tabstop VS softtabstop=0

Tags: tab-characters

Are this:

```
set noexpandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
```

..and this:

```
set noexpandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
```

..exactly the same? I thought that if `softtabstop=0`, then nothing happens if <kbd>Tab</kbd> is pressed, but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: What made you think `sts=0` prevents `<Tab>` from working?

Comment: @romainl As I understood it, `tabstop` simply defines the width of the `tab` character(for example `ts=4` means that it is four columns wide) while `softtabstop` actually defines amount of tabs and spaces inserted if `<Tab>` key is pressed. For example if `ts=4` and `sts=1` and one presses the `<Tab>` key, then only a single space character is inserted. Now if one makes another three spaces, then those are converted to single `tab`. This made me think that if `sts=0`, then nothing happens if `<Tab>` is pressed.

Comment: Set `softtabstop` to -1, `shiftwidth` to 0 and both options will then follow, whatever your `tabstop` setting is

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Thanks for this tip! However, I don't mind configuring all three. I was simply wondering why pressing `<Tab>` key inserts `tab` character or spaces(if `expandtab` is on) if `sts=0`. After all, `sts` controls how many columns vim uses when one hits `<Tab>` in insert mode and if `sts=0`, then IMHO it's logical to expect no characters when `<Tab>` key is pressed.

Comment: The only difference is when backspacing over a line that already had spaces for indentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of `'softtabstop'` as an additional control over `'tabstop'`, allowing you to reach indents "in between" tab stops.

With your indent setting, you don't actually need that, so the value of `'softtabstop'` doesn't really matter: You can set it to `0`, turning this off, set this equal to `'tabstop'`, in which case the effect is the same as off, or `:set softtabstop=-1 shiftwidth=0`, and both will follow the `'tabstop'` setting.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in `:h softtabstop`, the `softtabstop` indicates how many columns vim uses when you enter `<Tab>` in **insert mode**. Although it performs like `<Tab>` inserted, in fact, the vim mixes `<BS>` or `<Tab>` for that.

If you hit `<Tab>` in insert mode, the vim will act like:

```
if set expandtab
   always uses <BS>
else
   if softtabstop == 0
       always uses <Tab> // the number of columns is equal to tabstop
   else if softtabstop < 0
       the number of columns for <Tab> is equal to :shiftwidth
       && uses a mix of <BS> and <Tab>
   else
       uses a mix of <BS> and <Tab>
   end
end
```

For example,

In `:set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=2` case, the value of `tabstop` is large than the value of `softtabstop`, the vim will use two `<BS>` chars to represent one hit `<Tab>`.

In `:set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=2 softtabstop=2` case, the value of `tabstop` is equal to the value of `softtabstop`, the vim will use one `<Tab>` char to perform one hit `<Tab>`.

In `:set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=2 softtabstop=3` case, the value of `tabstop` is less than the value of `softtabstop`, the vim will use one `<Tab>` char and one `<BS>` char to perform one hit `<Tab>`.

In `:set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=2 softtabstop=0` case, the value of `softtabstop` is zero, the vim always uses `<Tab>`.

Therefore, **in your case**, `:set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=0` **does** equal to `:set noexpandtab shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4 softtabstop=4`.

In my opinion, it's better to use `tabstop == softtabstop` if you want to handle with `<Tab>`. Because the vim will not use a mix solution.

Comment: This is NOT an answer. This might serve as a good comment, but I strongly encourage you to either delete the answer or write out the answer properly.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/3077)

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg Thank you for remind me. I have updated the answer.

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I got your point. It make senses. I updated the answer. Thanks